# Find maximum element in hashtable with doubly linked list in each slot

Tags: algorithm, search, hashtable

There is a hash table, slots in an array, each slot has a doubly linked list, **unsorted.**

Total element count is `n`, slot count is `m`.

**What is the time complexity to:**

- Find the maximum element in whole hashtable.
- Find the successor element for a given element x.

They should be both `O(n)`, right? Because you have to iterate every element.

But, in the book `<The algorithm design manual 2nd>`, *page 90*, it says it's `O(n+m)`, but I don't get it.

Anyone, help to tell which is right? And, why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slots can be empty (have no elements in the list). You have to iterate all the slots to find all the non-empty lists, so that's O(m) work. Then you have to search all the lists, which is O(n) work. Total work: O(n + m).

Comment: Isnt it O(n*m)? For n lists with size m?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - OP indicated that the total number of elements in the entire table is n, not the size of each list. (It's m slots, each with a list of some size; total size of all lists is n.)

Comment: I knew this, I carelessly thought the book says `O(m + n/m)` ... it's my fault ... I don't know how did I though it in that way ... Anyway, thanks for help.